# pandas: identify "portions" along a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks more or less like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([list('AAABBBAAA')]).T
df.columns = [ 'type']
print(df)

   type
0     A
1     A
2     A
3     B
4     B
5     B
6     B
7     A
8     A
9     A
10    B
```

Assuming my DataFrame is already sorted, my goal is to identify "continuities" along column "type"; I would be happy with something like this:

```
   type     portion_ID
0     A             A0
1     A             A0
2     A             A0
3     B             B0
4     B             B0
5     B             B0
6     B             B0
7     A             A1
8     A             A1
9     A             A1
10    B             B1
```

I guess that something like

```
df['portion_ID'] = g['type'].apply(lambda s: s + some_magics())
```

would do the trick, but I didn't find "some_magic()" anywhere :-)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that fall on my mind is that you can keep state in an object:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.current = None
        self.current_label = None
        self.types = {}

def func(row, state):
    t = row['type']
    if state.current != t:
        state.current = t
        state.types[t] = state.types.get(t, -1) + 1
        state.current_label = t + str(state.types[t])
    return state.current_label

>>> df.apply(func, args=(State(),), axis=1)
0     A0
1     A0
2     A0
3     B0
4     B0
5     B0
6     B0
7     A1
8     A1
9     A1
10    B1
dtype: object
```

You can also calculate a column that contain the information if the state should change and then pass just a dictionary as a state:

```
df['change'] = ~ (df == df.shift())
def func(row, state):
    t = row['type']
    if row['change']:
        state[t] = state.get(t, -1) + 1
    return t + str(state[t])
df.apply(func, args=({},), axis=1)
```

Comment: Good! I like your second solution ; just wait until tomorrow to see if some other answers come. Thanks Viktor!